# How to change .jsp processing error page across all applications in IBM WebSphere 7.0

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

Our application is running on WebSphere application server 7.0. Whenever we hit some invalid url with ending .jsp we are getting JSP processing error page like below.

How to disable that.I want to show my own 404 error page which is configured under IBM HTTP Server. Only for .jsp extensions I am getting this error. All other requests are properly displaying my custom 404 error page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The WebSphere WebServer Plugin cannot override/replace error responses generated from the backend application server.  If you want it customized, you need to customize it on WAS.

Comment: Is there a way to put in general for applications instead of putting one for each?